# Java cannot find package in Inteliji

Tags: java, maven

I am using concurrent tree library in two different modules. When I try to build the project (I am using buck to build the project), second module gives me the following errors:

```
error: package com.googlecode.concurrenttrees.radixinverted does not exist
import com.googlecode.concurrenttrees.radixinverted.ConcurrentInvertedRadixTree;

error: package com.googlecode.concurrenttrees.radixinverted does not exist
```

I checked all of the previous posts about how to import dependencies  and the concurrent-tree maven library has been added successfully into the module and it detects all of its functions in a class. I tried everything that you think such as restarting and invalidating cache, opening a new project, etc but none of those work.

When I move my code under the first module it compiles without any problems but this is not the solution that I am looking for.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>onos-incubator</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>onos-incubator-api</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<description>ONOS incubating core API</description>

<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrent-trees</groupId>
        <artifactId>concurrent-trees</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

When I run mvn clean install, it doesn't generate any errors but when I try to build the project using buck it generates error

Comment: Show your POM files so we can understand your configuration.

Comment: I am developing a framework under ONOS which is a network operating system. I defined a package under one of its modules to include my codes. The configuration for that module is:

Comment: It is too long my pom files

Comment: You posted an answer, please [edit] your question. If it's too long, make a [mcve]

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrent-trees</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrent-trees</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: And the same thing in the first module which is maven application

Comment: The pom file for the first module is very similar to the pom file that I added

Comment: @JorgeCampos Do you need anything else that I should provide?

Comment: I think your problem is regarding conflict versions of the same LIB, since you said that this project is big, maybe somewhere else there is a transitive dependency to this library that do not have that package. The error is pretty straight forward. If it says that that package doesn't exists either it is not in the classpath or some other version that doesn't have it is being used. Try to pinpoint the problem reducing the code of the project to the point that only that library is needed. Then you add the others two or tree at a time.

Comment: You can also use the command `mvn dependency:tree` to see the hole dependency tree of your project. Do it in the parent folder.

Comment: When I execute dependency:tree command it gives me the following error:

Comment: [ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.onosproject:onos-api:1.10.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/adib/onos/core/api/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.googlecode.concurrent-trees:concurrent-trees:jar is missing. @ org.onosproject:onos-api:[unknown-version], /home/adib/onos/core/api/pom.xml, line 65, column 21

Comment: I fixed the last error by adding a version but I am still working on it to see what can I do to fix the original error

Comment: dependency-tree command has been executed successfully. I don't think the problem is because of conflict version since In all of pom files I specified the version